# Silverlight UI Validation, using WCF but not RIA

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Anyone have any recommendations on the best way to do this?  Data Annotations make sense, but I can't use them with my WCF services ([Data annotations on WCF service contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822328/data-annotations-on-wcf-service-contracts)) . I can't use RIA, because I need to send my services over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Implement IDataErrorInfo on your entities; you can use a validation framework to do most of the heavy lifting (I've used [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) for this purpose in WPF). Basically I don't think there's a built-in way, like with RIA services, so you need to write a bit more code.